# Will improved panel grounding resolve AM radio static?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I live in a manufactured house.  I have two electrical panels--one outside on the electrical pole where the electrical meter is at and another one in a utility room in the house.  The one on the pole is grounded and I have a 4 gauge ground wire running from the outside box to the one inside.

Recently, I installed an electric tankless water heater that draws 75 amps and I'm getting static on my AM house radio every time that I turn on the hot water.  I've been told that the panel inside my house to which the heater is connected needs an 8 ft ground rod.  The heater is grounded to the panel.

Comment: Welcome. I've modified your post title to ask a question. You didn't pose one. Feel free to revise further.

Comment: I wonder if the water heater is causing the interference, or if it's acting as a bridge for the interference to pass from one side of the circuit to the other.  Is this an AC powered radio?  If so, does it get the same static if you use it in any other rooms with the water heater off?  Do you have any other 220V appliances, and do any of them also cause static on the radio?

Comment: Definitely sounds like EMI being generated by the tankless water heater.  Does the owner's manual offer any suggestions?  Getting rid of this kind of noise can be tricky.

Comment: What make and model is the tankless heater in question?